# Buck2 can't create inotify watchers

Tags: buck, buck2

I'm following the [getting started guide for buck2](https://buck2.build/docs/getting_started/). My system is Ubuntu 22.04 (Jammy).

Installation worked with:

```bash
$ rustup install nightly-2023-05-28
cargo +nightly-2023-05-28 install --git https://github.com/facebook/buck2.git buck2
# After installation finished I get this version
$ buck2 --version
buck2 267ae15fcc862c9cd066152c8816e49f830d7715 <local>
```

Then I used `buck2 init` to create a `.buckconfig` containing:

```
[repositories]
root = .
prelude = prelude
toolchains = toolchains
none = none

[repository_aliases]
config = prelude
fbcode = none
fbsource = none
buck = none

[parser]
target_platform_detector_spec = target:root//...->prelude//platforms:default
```

However when I run `buck2 build //...`, I get the following errors:

```bash
$ buck2 build //...
Error initializing DaemonStateData

Caused by:
    0: Error creating a FileWatcher for project root `<REDACTED PROJECT ROOT PATH>`
    1: Creating notify file watcher
    2: OS file watch limit reached. about ["<REDACTED FILE>"]
```

Changing the inotify file watcher limit with `sudo sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288` (from default 65535), does not seem to do anything. I get the same error message *on the same file*.

It seems to be some other kind of error which is happening here, not related to the file watcher limit. Has anyone experienced this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into this issue, as well.  It turns out that there is a buck2-daemon that is already running with the previous inotify setting.  After changing the inotify setting, run:

```bash
buck2 kill # Can also do: buck2 killall
```

The next run will launch a new buck2-daemon with the new setting.